# file_get_contents in PHP when address in variable

Tags: php, parsing, hyperlink, file-get-contents

I have big problem with file_get_contents. When I do for example:

```
   $url=2
   $linkk = '.'.$this->address.'/'.$url.'.';
   $result = file_get_html($link)
```

WHERE url is changable number and $this->adress is a hyperlink. When I do `echo $linkk` and then paste it in browser it works correct!

What can be reason of this problem?

Comment: Uhm... `$linkk` vs. `$link`? BTW, you do not describe what your "problem" is.

Comment: $link and $linkk are not the same variable.

Comment: where is `file_get_contents`? Show the source of `file_get_html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this is a transcription typo, your variable is called `$linkk` (two k's), and your are calling `file_get_html()` with `$link` (one k).

Comment: I did mistake in paste code, but for my example it is correct anserw(so i accepted it). My real problem was that i don' t do html_entity_decode and in my hyperlink i had & so in code i had ;amp. Thanks for help

Comment: @kolek: If this answer isn’t right, don’t accept it; post the actual solution as a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

This extra `k` is causing the problem.

```
   $url=2
   $link = '.'.$this->address.'/'.$url.'.';
   $result = file_get_html($link);
```

If you still get problem then its the `file_get_html` function.